# How to push tabbar controller from one tabbar to another tabbarcontroller

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have been trying to push tabbarcontroller from tabbarcontroller view controller object.attached screenshot please give me some idea.I have tabbarcontroller as initial view and it has navigationcontroller-view controller as child and from view controller I want to push tabbarcontroller.When I push it my second tabbarcontroller tabbar is not visible and i cannot press back button to go back.

Comment: You have several different tabbars depending on where you are in the application? I think the tabbar is meant to be on root.

Comment: I have found some information in net.. acoording to that we can present tabbatcontroller.But if we have navigation controller of rootview then we can still push tabbarcontroller.But we cannot make two tabbars as root in storyboard.Please suggest some good ways.Currently I am trying to present modal view

Comment: @Narasimhaiah kolli i think u can do following.when pressing tab than change tab bar index ...and look like replace new tab in tabbar. its may helpful to u. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use exchange segue in storyboard and you can push the same tabbrcontroller twice.